# Adding submitted class to form input when button is clicked using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap, Angular JS and the Angular Payments plugin to create my form and validate/format credit card information. My goal is to display red text if the input is not validated once the form is submitted.  I was hoping to do this by adding the class "ng-submitted" when the button is clicked.

How would I go about properly doing this?

HTML - first part of my form as I have 2 sections.

```
<form name="ccform" class="ccform" ng-init="step = 1" novalidate>

              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row form-margin">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                      <div ng-show="step==1" >
                        <div ng-form="step1form" class="form-style">
                          <div class="col-xs-12">
                            <label class="sr-only" for="inputCardNumber">Credit Card Number</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control centerfield cardlogos" name="cardnumber" ng-model="number" payments-validate="card" payments-format="card" payments-type-model="type" ng-class="ccform.number.$card.type" placeholder="0000 0000 0000 0000" required/>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn add-button" ng-disabled="!step1form.$valid" ng-click="step = 2">Add card</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
.ng-valid {
  color:#4cae4c !important;
}

.ng-invalid {
  color: none !important;
}

input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty{
   color: #000 !important; 
}

input.ng-invalid.ng-dirty.ng-submitted {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Comment: If your button is set up to be default submit action on the form as per the [form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) directive docs, then your example should "just work". In other words - change `button` to an input submit.

Comment: Can you describe what output your, what appear to be, validation directives are giving. Are they setting validity, ie form.field.$error.errorType, or some other method?

Comment: You can also make use of the bootstrap class has-error and attach it to the div.form-group element using a ngClass conditional.